# Apache Jmeter - Selenium test with Firefox headless mode

Tags: selenium, jmeter, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I would like to run my test script in Apache Jmeter with Firefox Driver Config but I couldn't set up the headless mode and the setAcceptInsecureCerts(true).

I execute the Jmeter with the following command from CLI:

```
jmeter -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="c:\DEVTOOLS\PERFORMANCE_TEST\FIREFOX_GECKO_DRIVER\geckodriver.exe"
```

Unfortunately, the test target site does not use valid or secure certification at the moment, 
so I need to set up to accept insecure cert somehow.

Here is my code snippet:

```html
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui,org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions)

var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20)

pkg.FirefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true)
```

```
**I got the following error:**
2020-06-02 13:27:59,024 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: pkg.FirefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts is not a function in <eval> at line number 4
```

I don't know how is it possible to add the headless argument and AcceptInsecureCerts(true)
to Jmeter code.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something you can control using WebDriver Sampler, the options are in:

1. Patch [FirefoxDriverConfig.java](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/FirefoxDriverConfig.java) code where FirefoxDriver initialization happens and replace the WebDriver Sampler plugin under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation with your own version
2. Switch to the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) where you can instantiate your own FirefoxDriver with whatever capabilities/preferences/command-line arguments you want
3. If you're not able or not willing to go for the above options you can set `acceptInsecureCerts` preference using Firefox Driver Config element:

   [image]

   and if your system doesn't have GUI you can use i.e. [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to act as a virtual display like it's described in [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) article

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. 
Finally I used PhantomJs Driver with its config, because it gives the --web.security=false, --ignore-ssl-errors=true options to step out this issue. 

I haven't try it the points 1, 2 what you mentioned, but I think they maybe solve the configuration issue.